# Controller has required constructor arguments and does not exist in the container. Did you forget to define the controller as a service?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, controller

Im starting a project with symfony 6 and I have several contexts with their kernel, routes, services, etc... I'm trying to inject a depency to the controller constructor but it doesn't detect it and returns the error.

[image]

Composer.json

```
        "psr-4": {
            "CourtsReservationApp\\Context\\Backoffice\\Backend\\": "context/backoffice/backend/src",
            "CourtsReservationApp\\": ["src"]
        }
    },
```

RandomNumberGenerator Interface

```
<?php
namespace CourtsReservationApp\Backoffice\Domain;

interface RandomNumberGenerator
{
    public function generate(): int;
}
```

Implementation RandomNumberGenerator

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace CourtsReservationApp\Backoffice\Infrastructure;

use CourtsReservationApp\Backoffice\Domain\RandomNumberGenerator;

final class PhpRandomNumberGenerator implements RandomNumberGenerator
{
    public function generate(): int
    {
        return random_int(1, 5);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace CourtsReservationApp\Context\Backoffice\Backend\Controller\HealthCheck;

use CourtsReservationApp\Backoffice\Domain\RandomNumberGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class HealthCheckGetController
{
    public function __construct(private RandomNumberGenerator $generator)
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => true,
            "number" => $this->generator->generate()
        ]);
    }
}
```

services.yaml

```
parameters: null
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        
    CourtsReservationApp\Context\Backoffice\Backend\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
        
    CourtsReservationApp\Backend\:
        resource: '../../../../src/*'
```

BackofficeKernel

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace CourtsReservationApp\Context\Backoffice\Backend;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

final class BackofficeBackendKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    private const CONFIG_EXTS = ".{xml, yaml, yml}";

    public function getProjectDir(): string
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__);
    }

    public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        $contents = require $this->getProjectDir() . '/config/bundles.php';
        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if ($envs[$this->environment] ?? $envs['all'] ?? false) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RoutingConfigurator $routes): void
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir() . '/config';

        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/*.yaml');
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader):void
    {
        $container->addResource(new FileResource($this->getProjectDir() . '/config/bundles.php'));
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir() . '/config';

        $loader->load($confDir . '/services' . self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        //$loader->load($confDir . '/services_' . $this->environment . self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        //$loader->load($confDir . '/services/*' . self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    }
}
```

I have tried running composer dump-autoload, bin/console cache:clear and remove folder var/cache.

Thanks!

Comment: `resource: '../src/Controller/'` needs to point to wherever your controllers actually reside.  You can use `bin/console debug:container HealthCheckGetController` to verify you have the correct configuration.  I'm also not sure if your random number generator service will be picked up as well but one problem at a time.  Your Kernel class looks suspiciously like a Symfony 5 kernel class.  As a final bit of unsolicited advice, make sure this DDD approach is really worth the effort.

Comment: ````bin/console debug:container HealthCheckGetController```` return a error : ````No services found that match "HealthCheckGetController"````. I am following a ddd tutorial for educational purposes.

Comment: Which means that autowire is not picking up your controller class.  Just like the original error message indicates.  You need to fix the resource I pointed out to you or manually define (and tag) your controller service.

Answer (score 1):

This can be cause by an incorrect namespace on the controller.
Please check the Namespace and the corresponding folder structure and file name, it all needs to match.
Example:

```
# src/Controller/Dashboard/MyController.php
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Dashboard;
...

class MyController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    ...
}
```